# Readfile() отдать файл через http

Tags: php, yii

Доброго времени суток знатоки ! Вопрос видимо очень простой, но я первый раз работаю с файлами в php, поэтому прошу понять и простить! В общем у меня есть ссылка на сервер с файлами и мне нужно при запросе клиента оттуда брать файл и отдавать ему. Я ознакомился в инете с руководствами и написал такой код

```
        $file = 'http://some_server/some_directory/some_link.apk';

        if (ob_get_level()) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        readfile($file);
```

Но как я не мучился - он упорно не хочет отдавать файл! Если указываю на локальный файл, то отдает исправно. Проверял php.ini, allow_url_fopen и allow_url_include включены. Максимальный размер скачиваемого файла соответствует размеру файла. Кстати работаю я на локальном сервере xampp и фнеймворке yii, php версия - 5.4.27. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код должен работать, если в настройках php не отключена опция `allow_url_fopen`. Проверьте, что выдаёт:

```
echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen'); // нужна 1 или TRUE
```

У меня ваш код работает за небольшим изменением. Для обёртки "http://" [не доступны](http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.http.php) ф-ии группы `stat()` - среди них `filesize()`. Поэтому надо отказаться от заголовка с размером файла. Либо сначала сохранять копию на сервере, и отдавать уже сохранённый файл.

Вот такой код у меня работает и выдаёт лого php с оф. сайта:

```
if( !ini_get('allow_url_fopen')){
    echo "'allow_url_fopen' is off\n";
    exit(1);
}

$file = "http://php.net/images/logo.php";

header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

readfile( $file);
```

Comment: Да, к сожалению нужно отдавать на скачивание именно на нашем сайте, а не на источнике. Если вам будет не сложно, не могли бы точнее показать, что мне поможет. Я ознакомился с документацией, что вы скинули, но что то не нашел, того что мне поможет.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное !!! Очень выручили меня ! Проблема оказалась в header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)). Теперь работает, как надо)

Comment: Рад, что помог. Возможно, вы столкнётесь с проблемой нагрузки, т.к. передаваемый файл занимает память на время передачи. 10 одновременных скачиваний, и могут быть проблемы. Создаёте новый вопрос на Хэшкоде, когда столкнётесь с этим. Есть решения  ; )

Answer (score 0):

Данный пример потребляет много памяти:

```
    $file = 'http://some_server/some_directory/some_link.apk';
    $basename = preg_replace('#(.*)\/#u', $file);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $basename);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($file)/1024);

    echo file_get_contents($file);
```