# Загрузка картинки в зависимости от статуса проета

Tags: php

Добрый день, есть задача,
возвращать картинку виджета в зависимости от статуса проекта , то есть если проект платит возвращаем зеленую картинку, если не платит красную и т.д

ссылка виджета формируется один раз и примерно выглядит так site.com/informer/counter/ru/100/66
где 100 это размер а 66 это id проекта

но нам нужно в зависимости от статуса по ссылке возвращать разные картинки при этом ссылку мы не меняем

на странице выводится картинка site.com/informer/counter/ru/100/66 
формируется она так

```
return '<img src="/img/informer/ru_100_100.png">';
```

но виджетом я не могу ее отобразить

код виджета примерно такой

```
<a href="https://site.com/project/test-prevyu" target="_blank"><img src="https://site.com/informer/counter/ru/114/66" border="0" alt="Обзор проекта"/></a>
```

как правильно сделать чтобы получать эту картинку в виджете ?
PS не используя фрейма

Comment: вам нужно чтобы по одной и той же ссылке могла возвращаться разная картинка, или что?

Comment: да имя картинки я могу формировать на стороне контролера и возвращать

Comment: вам нужно, чтобы пхп скрипт саму картинку отдавал, а не ссылку на нее.

Comment: что нибудь вроде такого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379637/223826

Comment: супер , спасибо все заработало